# Access Octopus Deploy variables scoped with `Octopus.Deployment` in Python

Tags: python, octopus-deploy

I am developing some Octopus Deploy steps using Python.
This works up to the point where I want to get this variable:

```py
err = get_octopusvariable('Octopus.Deployment.Error')
```

Which throws an exception with a message of `'Octopus.Deployment.Error'`
This is strange as variables as `Octopus.Environment.Name` are retrievable.

Is there any other way of getting this variable? I could use `requests` to get the value through API but I think that this would be quite terrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the variable is not defined if no error is present.
Wrap the assignment in a try/except.